# Flash: Is it possible to `srand`?

Tags: flash, random

Like the title suggests… Is it possible to `srand` Flash's `Math.random`?

I'm asking because I'd like to generate psudo-random numbers in a repeatable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. But in the past I have used [BitmapData.noise()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#noise%28%29) as a poor man's substitute. That takes a seed, and you can use it to fill a dummy bitmap with values from 0..255 (which can be extracted and treated as a ByteArray if you like). Not exactly suitable for cryptography, but it will work as a quick hack.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. You'd need to roll an implementation of your own.